# Copy generic value from struct to variable c++

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, copy

As said in the description i need to copy a value from a variable in struct to another one but it gives me no error and cmd keep crashing.

```
struct GateNode
{
    string gatename;
    bool gatenPos=1;
    vector<struct GateNode*>inputs;
    bool (*ptrf)(vector<bool>);//puntatore a una funzione;
};
```

Then in main()

```
int main()
{
vector<bool> Op;
GateNode *ptr,g;
ptr=&g;
Op[0]=ptr->gatenPos;
return 0;
}
```

Cmd crash and doesn't give me any error! How can i achieve this? if 
cout ptr->gatenPos it displays the correct value but i can't copy it!

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<bool> Op;
```

This creates a vector. The vector is empty. It does not contain anything.

```
Op[0]=ptr->gatenPos;
```

This assigns something to value #0 in `Op`, that is, the first value in `Op`. However, as we've just determined, `Op` is empty and does not contain any values. Assigning to a nonexistent value is undefined behavior, that often results in a crash.

You must insert a new value into a vector. `Op[something]` does not insert a new value in the vector, it merely replaces an existing value in the vector, which must exist. If it doesn't exist, the resulting behavior is undefined.

A `std::vector` contains several functions that insert new values into the vector, notably `push_back`() and `insert`(). In this case, `push_back`() will be appropriate:

```
Op.push_back(ptr->gatenPost);
```